# Material-ui FormControlLabel value is not reflecting the changes when updating the state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

I am working on a question/answer app, The app has a functionality that when user goes back to the previous question he should be able to see his/her previous answer. So in a component i am showing options in the form of radio buttons to user by looping over the choices. I am saving user current answers in an array in redux store. So when user goes back to previous question i fetch his/her last answer and update the RadioGroup value in componentDidUpdate() but it doesn't update FormControlLabel check.

```
            <FormControl component="fieldset">
                <RadioGroup
                  aria-label="position"
                  name="position"
                  value={this.state.answers}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                >
                  {this.state.currentChoices.map(choice => (
                    <FormControlLabel
                      value={choice.label}
                      control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                      label={choice.label}
                      labelPlacement="end"
                      key={choice.label}
                    />
                  ))}
                </RadioGroup>
              </FormControl>
```

i console the value of RadioGroup (i.e: this.state.answers) it is updating but FormControlLabel is not getting checked

Answer (score -1):

just get sure that the data types are correct. the value of the FormControlLabel is often getting converted to string. had the same problem right now.